# I'm unable to find a type for aws s3 event notifications in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, types, boto3

I am working in python and have a code that receives s3 event notifications via an SQS. I'm trying to find existing type support (for type hints and parsing using pydantic) for events such as s3:ObjectCreated - I would assume something must exist in libraries such as types_aiobotocore_s3, but I'm unable to locate a type that describes these events.
I don't want to write it myself, because it should probably already exist.

Can anyone please assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message sent from S3 to Lambda is not generated by Boto3, so those `aibotocore` typings would not be relevant here. I suggest trying the `S3Event` type in this [aws-lambda-typings](https://github.com/MousaZeidBaker/aws-lambda-typing?tab=readme-ov-file#types) library.

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for! From your answer I was able to discover also that aws lambda powertools for python has this type. Thanks a lot, much appreciated!

Comment: @Anorflame I forgot about AWS Lambda Powertools, definitely use that instead of the one I liked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample S3 event. This one came from the AWS Lambda 'Test' function:

```json
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789",
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH"
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "example-bucket",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "test%2Fkey",
          "size": 1024,
          "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It's not particularly complex. Almost everything is a string.

Comment: Thank you for you response. Maybe my question was not clear enough. I need to have a class that describes this structure, both for type hinting and hopefully for parsing the json (for instance pydantic's models implement parsing and creating a class instance from a json string/dict). I'm trying to find out whether such a definition already exists, similar to https://youtype.github.io/types_aiobotocore_docs/types_aiobotocore_s3/type_defs/#headobjectoutputtypedef for example.
I prefer to avoid retyping this structure in a new class by myself if possible.